# How to calculate the error bar (e.g. stdev.s) for a slope based on independent samples?

Tags: standard-error, excel

In my experiment, I prepared 6 identical samples in the beginning. At Time 1, 3 samples were sacrificed and analysed; at Time 2, the rest 3 samples were sacrificed and analysed. So I got the data as below. The slope (-0.5243) is obtained as the rate. Can I ask how to caculate the error bar of the slope? Do I need to do this experiment e.g. three times, and get three slopes to draw the error bar?

I do not think I can simply get three slopes from these 6 data points. Because I can get a slope either from "Time2_repeat1 - Time1_repeat1" or "Time2_repeat2 - Time1_repeat1". Is there a particular definition for the slope, e.g. "average slope", "individual slope"?

Time    repeat1 repeat2 repeat3 average STDEV.S

1   0.8628  0.8675  0.8661  0.8655  0.0024

2   0.3445  0.3343  0.3448  0.3412  0.0060

[image]

---

Thank you Glen_b. I have attached it as below according to your words.

Can I ask,

1) I use "VAR.S" for the VAR, is that correct?

2) When you say "standard error", do you mean "standard error of the mean"? If I can calculate the Standard Error of the Mean (SEM) by:
SEM = STDEV.S/sqrt(count(n))

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Sens slopes.  Bootstrapped re-sampling of variance (Mann-Kendall).  Look at 'trend' package in 'R'.

Answer (score 2):

The usual assumption of constant variance are not usually reasonable for percentage data (they might be okay in some situations). [Linearity might also matter if you're trying to infer anything but the means at those two particular times, or the change in mean there.]

In any case, if you're prepared to assume the population standard deviations are about the same at the two time periods then one easy way to get a standard error of the slope would be to fit a least squares regression line to the entire six values (i.e. *don't* average them first).

[i.e. Set up a y column by stacking the six y-values, and an x-column by stacking the times (three `1` values on top of three `2` values).]

There are a variety of equivalent available formulas for the standard error of the slope, but the following approach will probably be the easiest for you to implement. In simple linear regression,

$$\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat{\beta})=\frac{(1-R^2)}{n-2}\frac{\text{Var}(y)}{\text{Var}(x)}$$

The standard error of the slope is the square root of that.

[In Excel, you can get the slope using the `SLOPE` function, and the $R^2$ value using the `RSQ` function between the y and x values. The ordinary `VAR` functions are applied to the y and x columns and then `COUNT` to (say) the y-values (here assuming there are no missing values in the x-column) to get the $n$.]

In the simple case you have here the slope and its standard error can be calculated a bit more simply, but the approach here is more general.

Comment: Thank you Glen_b. I have attached it as below according to your words.

Can I ask,

1) I use "VAR.S" for the VAR, is that correct?

2) When you say "standard error", do you mean "standard error of the mean"? If I can calculate the Standard Error of the Mean (SEM) by: SEM = STDEV.S/sqrt(count(n))

Comment: @lanselibai 1. You can use either VAR.S or VAR.P as long as you only include the observations that are present for both variables in either variance (i.e. if some values are missing from either, they must be excluded from both variance calculations)  2. No, I mean the *standard error of the slope* (which is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the slope). Wasn't that what you asked for?

Comment: Or were you actually seeking a confidence interval for the line? (and if so, do you seek a pointwise or simultaneous interval?)

Comment: thank you. Sorry, I have poor statistic background. I was thinking, standard error, standard deviation and SEM are three different things. The thing is, I have several groups of slopes to plot into a figure, e.g. a bar chart. 

When I plot some average values (the mean of Time 1, the mean of Time 2), I can either use SEM or STDEV.S to draw the error bar.

So I wonder, when I plot the slope values, do I also have those two options like SEM and STDEV.S ?

Comment: When you're showing a mean you can either consider using a display to summarize the raw data (giving mean and sd of the data) or to give information about the estimate of the population mean (the estimate of the population mean and the standard error of the estimate). When you're looking at a slope, you're pretty much in the second situation (show the estimate of the slope and the standard error of the slope estimate). Arguably you could show the s.d. of the data about the line instead, but I think that would be better done by plotting the raw data vs time and drawing the line on that plot.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean the Var(β) you show in the equation is the "Standard Error of the Mean" of the slope?

Comment: @lanselibai No. Do you see right under the formula where it says "*The standard error of the slope is the square root of that*". Don't ignore that part. (incidentally, I chose this particular form of the variance in order that  it's easy to do in Excel -- the usual formula involves a lot more effort if you want to do it in Excel. because it's based on the sum of squared residuals). You may not find that particular formula anywhere in exactly that form .. but if you compare the results with the usual formula you'll see they're the same.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. I see, it should be the square root of the Var(β).

Can I ask, when we see "standard error", do we always mean the "standard error of the mean"? Thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily -- indeed in my answer above, the standard error being discussed isn't the standard error of the mean. However, if there's no statistic mentioned (i.e. it isn't explicitly specified what thing we're finding the standard error of) then often it's the standard error of the mean that's intended.

Comment: Thank you. I see. Thank you for all your help. There is a lot to learn for the statistic.